# Accidentally updated OpenSUSE Leap to 42.2

Tags: opensuse, gnome3

I accidentally updated Leap to 42.2 (installed Freecad from software.opensuse.org, trusted to add new repo, refresh, update...)

Gnome shell exits with error 127, no panels, nothing after login except for messengers that auto start.

I'd like to roll back to 42.1. How do I even start recovering from this?

Answer (score 0):

God bless snapper.

I didn't even know I had this on my system. This buddy has been making snapshots, so all it really took was

```
sudo snapper ls
```

Then see the list of snapshots, identify the critical pre-snapshot (labeled as important=yes) and

```
sudo snapper rollback <"PRE" snapshot ID>
```

The only problem is that package updater still lists ~2k updates, I have to figure out the way of telling it I don't want to switch to the new version...